# Why does copying from textarea to div and back not save state?

Tags: javascript, formatting

When I copy code from a textarea to a div and then back the content is no longer the same.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="ta" rows="10" cols="120"><p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation <ul><li>sfsD</li><li>sf234fw</li></ul> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." </p></textarea>
<br>
<button>Button</button>
<div id="container"></div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('button').click(function(){
            $('#container').html($('#ta').val());
            $('#ta').val($('#container').html());
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I copy the text from the textarea to the div everything is fine. But when I copy from the div back to the textarea, the value is now

```
<p> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </p>
<ul><li>sfsD</li><li>sf234fw</li></ul> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in 
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, 
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum." <p></p>
```

I'm not sure why this happens or how to fix it?! any ideas? This happens in FF and in chrome.

Comment: What is your reason for copying the content from a textarea to a div - there are probably better places to store it (as long as you don't need it visible)? If this is going to be a textarea that any old user can type into, there will be many other situations where your markup may be auto-corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('#ta').val($('#container').text());`

Answer (score 1):

The difference that I can see is down to the fact that you are placing markup illegally, `ULs` are not allowed within `P` tags... basically both browsers in question will break the `P` where they find other block level elements - they are basically autocorrecting your markup for you.

If you were to copy the markup they give back to you as the markup you place in your textarea there wouldn't be a change the next time you test your button.

Answer (score 1):

`val()` returns value (which can mean many different things depending on what the element is), while `html()` returns markup.

you can't mix and match the two calls and expect your input to match your output - pick one or the other to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

because `html()` returns the markup. Perhaps you need `text()`.